# Alternative to NAND chips

Tags: embedded, linux, non-volatile-memory

The company I work for is manufacturing a device with an ARM processor and embedded Linux. At the time of the project (a few years ago) our consultants relied on NAND flash chips with UBIFS as filesystem, due to project constraints:

- The device must always be bootable even after a power cut.
- The boot time of the device must always be the same, even after a power cut.

Unfortunately, power cut is the "normal" way our customers shut down their devices.
Unfortunately, the flash chip is no longer in production, so we are reassessing other alternatives: MMC embedded or SATA SSD. Something, in short, that if it goes out of production, we can find a replacement while maintaining the same identical FW.

I wonder if today the hw (SSD, eMMC, etc.) and sw (mainly filesystems) technologies allow me to stay within the constraints with devices other than NAND flash chips.

Comment: How big does it need to be?  For smaller embedded system images booting from an SPI NOR flash and uncompressing to a RAM disk can be very nice.

Comment: between 512MB and 1GB. The devices must store a lot of information, provided by the user, necessary for the operation of the device itself

The current implementation includes booting from NOR flash and saving the info on NAND flash.

Comment: It would actually be a good idea to bring in the flash vendors and have them present their solutions.

Comment: So the problem isn't actually boot safety, but rather safe storage of runtime data.

Comment: Does the NAND flash chips have a standard interface?  Can you user a different perhaps higher capacity NAND chip that is still in production?

Comment: eMMC is the way to go, but UBIFS, jffs2 etc. would do you no good then. The controller chip already does all that for you.

Comment: @crj11 I don't know what you mean by standard interface. We are using a 16Gb x 16 bit SLC chip. Unfortunately, it seems that SLC technology has been abandoned by all manufacturers and, worse still, the 16-bit interface is replaced by the 8-bit interface. Finally, as if that weren't enough, the chips found today have different timings and sizes of sectors.

Comment: @crj11 However, we must ensure that our firmware updates can run on both old and new NAND models. So if we do the problem we postpone it only by one year or two (when the chip chosen today will become obsolete) then the problem will reoccur, instead the life cycle of our device is expected to be around 15 years (and we are only 5 years old)

Comment: @Janka UBIFS and jffs2 can be stacked on character devices, while an eMMC is a block device, making it impossible to adopt these filesystems (and generally all those that are born to be stacked devices such as MTD). But which filesystem should I use on eMMC so that the constraints are met? I repeat: the boot must never fail after a power cut (i. e. the filesystem must not corrupt itself so that the boot does not stop), and the boot time must not be constant (it doesn't need a long fsck after a power cut).

Comment: @ChrisStratton The NOR contains only u-boot and kernel, but not the root filesystem (which is about 50MB large) which is in the NAND. The NAND then contains the runtime data but also the root filesystem.

Comment: You want XFS and may want to try BtrFS.

Comment: You could put a CPLD between the device and the storage to provide a consistent interface even though the memory changes with time.

Comment: @crj11 some of these differences are too much for a CPLD to handle; but they are mostly software settings anyway, so if the chip has an idcode typically done by runtime detection.

Comment: Have to taken a look at http://www.onfi.org/ , the Open NAND Flash Interface consortium?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a multi part answer.

1. I'd assume here that if a unit fails in the field you simply swap it out. The decision to scrap that board is then yours (how long do you WANT to keep the boards circulating). For your current boards you should have stock on hand of the NAND chips to allow for board failures and repair.
2. You'd produce future firmware that can support the 16bit NAND interface and whatever new storage interface you choose. For example in UBoot (if that's what you are using) you introduce the required drivers for the boot path.
3. I'd suggest using the SD/MMC interface (of which e.MMC is just one variant) since that can use a single lane to simplify changes.
   While speed is the concern for most MMC usage, it may be that you can tolerate a slower speed as long as it's consistent. 
   You could use a single lane interface over SPI as an interface (about as simple as you can get). [This](http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html) might get you started thinking about it.
   Certainly this would seem to minimize changes to your PCB.

Comment: I am frightened by a thought that I tried to arrange with the two following sentences (questions):
Let's suppose that under normal conditions, the boot time is x seconds. How long could the boot time be in the worst case after a power cut? Is it always possible to complete the device boot after a power cut?

Comment: Only you can know the boot time after a power failure, you are writing the software/firmware.

Comment: I'll give an example: if I chose eMMC with EXT4 I'd be quite sure that after a power cut the boot time would be much higher and moreover there would be the risk that the system wouldn't even be able to complete the boot. The only thing we have control over is choosing the filesyetm. That's why I wondered which block device filesystem guarantees boot times after a power cut, about the same as normal boot.

Comment: No matter the file system used, the system can be guaranteed to boot at least through the bootloader ...the real question is can the OS recover from any FS damage that occurs during power fail. That's a different question entirely, unrelated to your question on NAND flash implementations. You could start  looking at fsck performance here: https://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2008/08/08/fast-ext4-fsck-times/

Comment: I think it is really relevant. We need to change technology and move away from NAND. The NAND with UBIFS guarantees constant boot times (even after a power cut) and guarantees that the filesystem does not suffer any damage that would not allow the boot. The question we ask ourselves is: supposing we choose eMMC as our memory, which filesystem can we mount on it to have the same guarantees as those mentioned above?
The bootloader is not the subject of my question, as it resides in a NOR. What we are interested in is after the kernel starts, which then has to mount the root filesystem.

Comment: eMMC is built with NAND ...it's just managed NAND as opposed to a raw device. The management is for write levelling and bad block management. It does not guarantee you won't need to fsck the drive or that you may have incomplete flushes to memory during a power failure.

Comment: we have done some tests (some very intensive). The current device with NAND and UBIFS has been subjected to more than 140000 power cuts that occurred at random times, ranging from a few seconds to a few minutes. The system has always been able to boot and the maximum boot time obtained was about 4.5% higher than the nominal (which is about 9.5 seconds).
Which filesystem mounted on eMMC provides similar performance?

Comment: @mastupristi: What makes file system recovery really slow is high number of files in complex tree structures. If the filesystem is read-only, no data will ever be changed, and a power cut will never require a recovery. One could make a read-only operating system partition, and one with all files being written by the device. This reduces recovery time a lot. But you didn't say what type of data is in on the memory.